# Unrecognized database format accdbb

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb

I'm trying to connect c# windows form with Access database and when trying to add new data source I see an error message saying: "Unrecognized database format..."

When I open Advanced option this is how looks like the connection string created based on the previously chosen options:
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source="C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\Access Databases\sample_database.accdb"

I'm using Office 365, Visual Studio Community 2015, .Net Framework 4.5 or 4.6.

I guess it should be used Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB but not sure which version fits here. I'm not sure if this version is obsolete in my case:
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=13255

Can someone explain me what is missing here and which version of the missed component should be installed? Or something else is an issue.

Many thanks!

Comment: In which Access version the DB file was created? You need to use ACE OLEDB provider inside connection string if it has ACCDB extension (`Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\Users\MyPC\Documents\Access Databases\sample_database.accdb`).

Comment: Your question about Access is answered in the initial post. I'm using MS Access as a part of Office 365 subscription.

Comment: Try https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/